# Is it Possible to Update the Table in PerlCGI

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I am fetching the records from the database which has tons of records. So building the complete table structure and printing the table takes a long time to display the records as each record needs post processing also. I wanted to know is it possible to update the table with the table after processing each record.

```
push @rows, TR(
    { class => 'row-2-center' },
    td( { class => 'category-center' }, [ FirstName LastName PhoneNumber ] )
);

$sth = db_cmd( $dbh1, $statement );
while ( $r = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
    push @rows, TR( { class => 'row-2' }, @TEMP );    # Temp is the processed value
}

print table( { class => 'width100', cellspacing => 1 }, @rows );
```

This is how am processing now. but i need it like

```
push @rows, TR(
    { class => 'row-2-center' },
    td( { class => 'category-center' }, [ FirstName LastName PhoneNumber ] )
);

print table( { class => 'width100', cellspacing => 1 }, @rows );

$sth = db_cmd( $dbh1, $statement );

while ( $r = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
    push @rows, TR( { class => 'row-2' }, @TEMP );    # Temp is the processed value
    print table( { class => 'width100', cellspacing => 1 }, @rows );
}
```

but it writes it as a different table i need to update the same table. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Two recommendations: 1) Only load a small subset of the data and allow users to "page" through it (i.e. click a button to show the next page of results) 2) Load a minimal page and fetch the results using AJAX, updating the page as data becomes available. You could implement one or both of these.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? The browser will not get any of the HTML file before the CGI script has terminated and the entire final table is complete, so what could you win by creating first a table and then updating it? If this is a matter of *rendering speed* (the browser normally needs to get the entire table before it can render it), then this would be a client-side issue and could be addressed using `table-layout: fixed` in CSS, with great care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use one table, and output one row at time,

```
use CGI qw/*table TR td/;

print start_table();

print TR (
  {class => 'row-2-center'},
  td ({class => 'category-center'}, [qw/FirstName LastName PhoneNumber/])
);
# print TR ..

print end_table();
```

Comment: The wildcard `*` in your [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) statement is new to me.  Is that standard functionality of [`Exporter`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html)?  Or something particular to [`CGI`](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html)?

Comment: @Miller Looks like a [special feature of CGI](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#SPECIAL-FORMS-FOR-IMPORTING-HTML-TAG-FUNCTIONS): "With a few exceptions (described below), `start_tag_name` and `end_tag_name` functions are not generated automatically when you use CGI. However, you can specify the tags you want to generate start/end functions for by putting an asterisk in front of their name, or, alternatively, requesting either "start_tag_name" or "end_tag_name" in the import list."

Comment: @Miller Exporter mentions only *typeglob so it seems that it is `CGI` specific.

Comment: @mpapec Yes, that was the conclusion that I came to as well.  Part of me wondered whether or not this would be a useful feature to add to `Exporter`, since it would be very easy to do so?  However, I believe that given most modules have fortunately moved to OO design, there really isn't the need to export a whole class of functions like was done in the original CGI module.